# Check whether the equation $3x^3+5y^5+z^3+4z=13$ defines the function $z(x,y)$ at a point $A(1,1,1)$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Consider the equation
> $$
> 3x^3+5y^5+z^3+4z=13
> $$
> Check whether the equation defines the function $z(x,y)$ at a point $A(1,1,1)$

I don't understand what am I supposed to in this problem. Can someone give me a clue as to how to start?

Comment: I think you are supposed to check whether the given point lies on the cuve. Other wise, the question is meaningless.

Comment: You’re supposed to check that in a neighborhood of $A$, for $(x,y)$ given, there is a unique $z$ solution of the equation. Implicit function theorem may be useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$3 x^3+5 y^5+z^3+4 z=13\tag{1}$$
plugging $x=1,y=1$ we get
$$z^3+4 z+8=13\to z^3+4 z-5=0\to (z-1) \left(z^2+z+5\right)=0$$
which has the only real solution $z=1$

therefore $(1)$ defines implicitly a function at $(1,1,1)$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
z^3+4z=f(z)=g(x,y) = 13-3x^3-5y^5
$$

but $f(z)$ has inverse because $f'(z) = 3z^2+4 > 0\ \  \forall z\in\mathbb{R}$ so there exists

$$
z = f^{-1}\left(g(x,y)\right)\ \ \forall \{x,y\}\in\mathbb{R}^2
$$

Attached a plot representation for $z = f^{-1}\left(g(x,y)\right)$. In black the point $(1,1,1)$

[image]

Comment: at point (z=1),$ f(z)=z^3+4z=5$. At point (1,1), $g(x,y)=13-3-5=5$, that means at point (1,1,1), f(z)=g(x,y) which means curves f(z) and g(x,y) have a common point like (1, 1, 1). I  do not see a function like z(x, y).

Comment: Sorry but I didn't follow your considerations.